# search string in list and return list value

Tags: python-3.x, list, xlrd

I extract some values from excel sheet as list.
list = [cap-0101-01010, ture-adb-0111-110, bean-KG-0101-2020, fire-Good-2020191, good-9092929, memory-2020939-KGY, excute-odo-2020393, .... , ending-doo-9090922]

If there is matched string in the list with specific string(ex: XY CUTE BGN-excute-odo-2020393), then return excute-odo-2020393 in the list.

Here is my code, but it is not working.

```
list = []
cnt = 0
book1 = xlrd.open_workbook('D:/@. ex.xlsx')
sheet = book1.sheet_by_name('List')
for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
    row = sheet.row(rowidx)
    for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
        list.append(str(cell.value))
book1.release_resources()
del book1


tmp = ''
for mfr in list:
    if mfr in safetyreportid:
        tmp = mfr
        print(mfr)
print(tmp)
```

And below is the error message when I execute aboce source code.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\AB\Desktop\parser.py", line 99, in 
> print(mfr)
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel sheet, there is space like below, then, in the row of apple, the error is occured

```
banana
 apple
orange
```

Answer (score 1):

If the space at the beginning makes the problems you could compare the stripped strings. Like this: `"apple" == " apple"`  -> False, but `"apple".strip() == " apple".strip()`  -> True

But your error does not occur on my computer. I made an Excel file with a tab 'List' that contains strings (fruits) in the first column. Some without space, some some with space before and some with space before and after. Then, for saftyreportid I used `safetyreportid = ["apple", "strawberry", "lemon"]` and with your code there was no error (but only lemon found because of the space problem). Using `mfr.strip()`in the `if` and below it found all common words.

Perhaps your problem is in the format the saftyreportid is delivered in? (It says Encode Error!)

If your strings may contain backslashes (\) you should use the raw string format, I guess. `print("\xa0")` is different from `print(r"\xa0")`